# regex in java: matching BOL and EOL

Tags: java, regex

I try to parse windows ini file with the java under the Windows. Assume that content is:

```
[section1]
key1=value1
key2=value2
[section2]
key1=value1
key2=value2
[section3]
key1=value1
key2=value2
```

I use the folowing code:

```
Pattern pattSections = Pattern.compile("^\\[([a-zA-Z_0-9\\s]+)\\]$([^\\[]*)", Pattern.DOTALL + Pattern.MULTILINE);
Pattern pattPairs = Pattern.compile("^([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)\\s*=\\s*([^$]*)$", Pattern.DOTALL + Pattern.MULTILINE);
// parse sections
Matcher matchSections = pattSections.matcher(content);
while (matchSections.find()) {
    String keySection = matchSections.group(1);
    String valSection = matchSections.group(2);
    // parse section content
    Matcher matchPairs = pattPairs.matcher(valSection);
    while (matchPairs.find()) {
        String keyPair = matchPairs.group(1);
        String valPair = matchPairs.group(2);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work properly:

1. The section1 doesn't match. It's probably because this starts not from the 'after EOL'. When I put the empty string before the `[section1]` then it matches.
2. The `valSection` returns '\r\nke1=value1\r\nkey2=value2\r\n'. The `keyPair` returns 'key1'. It looks like ok. But the `valPair` returns the 'value1\r\nkey2=value2\r\n' but not the 'value1' as desired.

What is wrong here?

Comment: you're not excluding "new line" in the check for the value.

Comment: Ad 2. The pattern defined in `pattPairs` is greedy, thus matching until the end of the second key. You can read up on greedy and non-greedy matching and how to compensate here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html

Comment: Did you try replacing `\r\n` with `\n` first?

Comment: U no like http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/ ?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the `DOTALL` flag as you do not use dots at all in your pattern.

I think Java treats `\n` itself as newline so `\r` won't be processed. Your pattern:

```
^\\[([a-zA-Z_0-9\\s]+)\\]$
```

won't be true, but insted

```
^\\[([a-zA-Z_0-9\\s]+)\\]\r$
```

will.

I recommend you ignore MULTILINE too and use the following patterns as line separators:

```
(^|\r\n)
($|\r\n)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first regex just worked (isn't it a problem on how you read the file?), and the second one was added the "?" sign to use it in a reluctant way.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String content = "[section1]\r\n" +
        "key1=value1\r\n" +
        "key2=value2\r\n" +
        "[section2]\r\n" +
        "key1=value1\r\n" +
        "key2=value2\r\n" +
        "[section3]\r\n" +
        "key1=value1\r\n" +
        "key2=value2\r\n";

        Pattern pattSections = Pattern.compile(
                "^\\[([a-zA-Z_0-9\\s]+)\\]$([^\\[]*)", Pattern.DOTALL
                        + Pattern.MULTILINE);
        Pattern pattPairs = Pattern.compile(
                "^([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)\\s*=\\s*([^$]*?)$", Pattern.DOTALL
                        + Pattern.MULTILINE);
        // parse sections
        Matcher matchSections = pattSections.matcher(content);
        while (matchSections.find()) {
            String keySection = matchSections.group(1);
            String valSection = matchSections.group(2);
            // parse section content
            Matcher matchPairs = pattPairs.matcher(valSection);
            while (matchPairs.find()) {
                String keyPair = matchPairs.group(1);
                String valPair = matchPairs.group(2);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work in my case. The `^` doesn't match as the BOL at the BOF in the 1st pattern and the symbol $ is treated as simple $ but not the EOL in the `[^$]` in the 2nd pattern.

Comment: have you tried to execute the code as it is suggested? Maybe you can present a sample of you ini file...